# How to properly create and resolve Observable of Observables (RxJS)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

In my Angular app, I have multiple services that depend on each other. So I created a dependency map for them. Here is a shortened example:

```
let accountInitialization$: Observable<void>;
let productInitialization$: Observable<void>;

const dependenciesMap = {
  accountService: [],
  productService: [
    accountInitialization$ // There could be one or more dependencies
  ]
}

accountInitialization$ = this.getDependencies(dependenciesMap.accountService)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => {
      return this.accountService.initialize();
    })
  );

productInitialization$ = this.getDependencies(dependenciesMap.productService)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(_ => {
      return this.productService.initialize();
    })
  );

accountInitialization$.subscribe(() => {
  this.progressUpdate.next(StartUpProgressUpdate.AccountsInitialized);
});

productInitialization$.subscribe(() => {
  this.progressUpdate.next(StartUpProgressUpdate.ProductsInitialized);
});

forkJoin([accountInitialization$, productInitialization$]).subscribe(
  () => {
    // do some work
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error); // This is where I see the error specified below
  }
);
```

So the Product Service depends on Account Service initialization. The getDependencies function looks like:

```
private getDependencies(dependencies: Observable<void>[]) {
if (dependencies.length) {
  return forkJoin(dependencies);
}
return EMPTY;
```

}

What I want to achieve in this example is, before Product Service is initialized, make sure Account Service is initialized first. Right now I'm getting this error

> ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

It looks like the `.initialize()` functions are never called...

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `forkJoin`, you have to use `switchMap`. I am not sure how to structure it how you have it but something like this:

```
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
productInitialization$ = this.accountInitialization$.pipe(
  switchMap(accountInitializtion => {
    console.log('account initialization finished with: ', accountInitialization);
    // switch to this observable once complete
    return this.productService.initialize();
  });
)
```

For you it might be different, but look into `concatMap`, `switchMap`, `mergeMap` to go from one `Observable` to another.

Comment: Thank you! That simplified my code for sure. However, I am still getting the same error: `ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.` I updated the post with more details.

Comment: Does `return this.accountService.initialize();` and `return this.productService.initialize();` return `Observables`? If not, that could be the issue. `mergeMap` expects an `Observable` to be returned. And make sure `accountInitialization$` and `productInitialization$` return `Observables` as well.

Comment: Yup, `this.accountService.initialize()` returns an `Observable<void>`, and same for productService. `accountInitialization$` and `productInitialization$` are also `Observable<void>`. I'll keep you updated as I try more different things, thanks for your help.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to add one more detail. My inner observable is a list of observables that's' been forkjoined.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by this but you should look into the `tap` operator to debug. You basically can do `tap(value => { console.log(value); debugger; }),` and you can debug what's going on at each step of the streams. https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap